# Gitlab sort multiple repositories by last commit date

Tags: gitlab

In my internal gitlab site there are a lot of repositories and I want to find repositories which don't' have commits for so long .

In order to do this , I searched  as last updated but it's not accurately reflect , looks like it's a bug .
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could be similar to [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss` issue 56227](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/56227):

> For example, I have a project `testing-dev-project` in a group.
> It displays that it was last updated 1 week ago.

> Using the inspector, the time is Dec 28, 2018. However, if I query the project with the API, I get the "last_activity_at":"2018-10-26T12:46:34.372-07:00".
> You can also check by going to the `Project -> Activity` or `Project -> Settings -> Audit Events`.

But:

> This has likely always been the behavior - if a database migration touches something in a project then the updated_at timestamp is automatically updated by Rails.

This is also mentioned in [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 25862](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/25862): "Show project creation dates when sorting group page on this attribute"

> For some reason, `updated_at` was updated fairly recently. I suspect a migration such as the one that encrypted the runners token column may have touched every project.
> As a result, the `updated_at` column may have been updated recently, and the projects appear to have been touched more recently than they should.

> Last updated being out of order due to the issues described in [`gitlab-org/gitlab-foss` issue 27181](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/27181)

That last issue is the most relevant, still opened, and finishes with:

> The discrepancy between the actual sort order and the displayed updated time is due to the fact that it displays the project's `last_updated_date` value, while sort is based on `last_updated_at`.

> It's not immediately obvious to me why these values are so different, it seems like they should be very close.
> I've submitted a MR that sets the list to display values from `last_updated_at`, though I'm not sure if a better long term solution would be to change the triggers that set `last_updated_date` and use that for sorting instead.

This issue is moved to [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 17017](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17017).

---

See also GitLab 14.10 [MR 82488](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/merge_requests/82488): "Project list: order by real last update"